# how to reshape a 4D tensorflow to a 2D

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an X_train image as:

```
X-train (37248, 32, 32, 3)
```

y_train (37248, 43)

I have a feed-dictionary as

```
train_feed_dict = {features: X_train, labels: train_labels}
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    session.run(loss, feed_dict=train_feed_dict)
```

My features is:

```
features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32, 32, 3]) 
features = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 3072])
```

But when I run the code I get this error, reshaping does not seem to take place.

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (37248, 32, 32, 3) for Tensor 'Reshape_5:0', which has shape '(?, 3072)'
```

Comment: I think you need to keep track of features vs reshaped features. Try using `features2 = tf.reshape(features, [ -1, 3072])`.

Comment: Alas, No, same error.

Comment: What is the shape that goes into the `feed_dict` (`features` -- assuming that `X_train` is the shape you described above)? If they're the same, maybe it's the processing inside the graph.

Comment: features is (?, 3072) if place a print (features.get_shape()) after features = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 3072])

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error was two prong:

I had to split the data into np.array() format and
flat_features = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 3072])

having features=tf.reshape(features, [-1, 3072]), I had two problems so just changing the name t flat_features by itself did not work

so @drpng was also right in his comment